# is python subprocess module quirky?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

earlier today this code worked as I wanted it to. Now it doesn't. I want it to run airodump and store the output to a csv file (command line option). After a few seconds kill the process.

```
def find_networks():
airodump = subprocess.Popen(["airodump-ng","-w","airo","--output-format","csv","mon0"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  
time.sleep(10)
try:
    os.kill(airodump.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    if not airodump.poll():
        print "shouldn't have had to do this.."
    airodump.kill()
    if not airodump.poll():
        print "shouldn't have had to do this....."
    airodump.terminate()
    if not airodump.poll():
        print "shouldn't have had to do this........"
except OSError:
    print "?"
    pass
except UnboundLocalError:
    print "??"
    pass        
return_code = airodump.wait()
print return_code
```

(the output here is:
shouldn't have had to do this..
shouldn't have had to do this.....
-9)

Earlier it would do exactly what I said (same code). The negative 9 is worrisome, earlier I was getting 1, but the process still DOES die which is all thats important, but not due to os.kill statement, which is wierd. That's not the big problem though. All i need is that .csv file. With this implementation, the csv file is completely empty - it is made but nothing ever put in it. If I run subprocess without stdout set to PIPE, the csv file IS created and populated, but I cant do it that way- I have to keep the stdout off the screen though.

Is stdout=subprocess.PIPE causing the data to be "written" to a nonexistent csv file in PIPE-land???

Comment: It seems to me that `airodump.kill()` and `airodump.terminate()` should be swapped. `kill` sends SIGKILL, unconditinal process termination, whereas SIGTERM just asks the process to quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to reproduce what's happening on your machine with your example code. One thing that might be causing some problems though: You should only use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` if you are actually intending to read from the pipe. If you don't, the process will block once it generates enough output to fill up the pipe buffer.

If all you want to do is to hide stdout and stderr, you can do this:

```
airodump = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=open("/dev/null", "w"), stderr=open("/dev/null", "w"))
```

Or better yet:

```
import os
airodump = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=open(os.devnull, "w"))
```

Or if you are using Python 3, you can use [subprocess.DEVNULL](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL).

Comment: That is what I was looking for. yeah, there was no good reason to send it to pipe, I was just trying to keep it off the screen. So that does everything I need it to do, thanks.

one other thing, though. After the script completes, anything I type doesn't  appear on the screen (going to /dev/null I suppose). I can run commands still, and the output of those commands shows up, just text that I type will not appear?

Comment: How are you running your script? From the command line, or an IDE, or double clicking an icon? You may want to create another SO question, as the answer may not be simple.

Answer (score 0):

since you send the output to PIPE, you should explicitly read it out if you want it, you can then write it to a local file. Sth like:

```
airodump = subprocess.Popen(["airodump-ng","-w","airo","--output-format","csv","mon0"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
... # wait the command to complete
open("the_file_you_want_to_store_output", "w").write(airodump.stdout.read())
```